# Passive form of "having strong interest"

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice, active-voice

I have strong interest in something.
For a passive version: something catch my strong interest, but I think 'catch' is not idiomatic.

Does anyone have any idea about that?

Comment: If you already have the interest in sth., it already **caught** your interest. 'catch' is only for when you don't have the interest yet: "I haven't really tried it before, but once I do, I think it will really catch my interest." Also, you wouldn't use "strong interest" to signify the intensity, rather you would emphasize how much your interest is caught, eg. "It **really** caught my interest"

Comment: Also consider *capture*. It has a suggestion that the thing is so compelling, you are held captive.

Comment: For more intensity, there's **grab** "It really grabbed my interest."

Answer (score -1):

active voice:  It interests me.

passive voice: I am interested [in it].

Comment: That's not passive voice.

Comment: Do tell why "I am interested" is not passive voice.

Comment: Because it's a linking verb.  Passive voice would be "I am interested BY it."

Comment: _Interested_ is just an adjective, like _red_ or _tired_, Predicate adjectives are often formed from verb participles, but they are not passive verbs. _I an interested in it, I am tired of it, I am tall enough,_ all are predicate adjectives, none are passive.

Comment: "I am interested by it" suggests an immediate attraction, like if you were stroking something that has an attractive texture. If you are merely expressing a general interest in a topic or activity, then you would use adjectival "interested in". Compare "I am attracted by/to it."